# Entity Framework Linq Query of 3 tables

Tags: entity-framework

I have this 3 table query that doesn't return any results. Does anybody have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? _id is a global variable.

```
'If there is a guest list then display each person in it
    Dim guests = (From g In myEntities.GuestLists
                  From p In myEntities.Pictures
                  From u In myEntities.UserProfiles
                  Where g.EventID = _id
                  Where p.UserID = g.GuestID
                  Where u.UserID = g.GuestID
                  Select New With {p.ImUrl, u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.UserID}).SingleOrDefault()
    Repeater1.DataSource = guests
    Repeater1.DataBind()
```

This syntax works for a single table or two table query so I assumed 3 tables would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the tables.

Like this (untested!)

```
From g In myEntities.GuestLists
Join p In myEntities.Pictures On g.GuestID Equals p.UserID
Join u In myEntities.UserProfiles On g.GuestID Equals u.UserID
Where g.EventID == _id
Select New With {p.ImUrl, u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.UserID}
```